# Matrix multiplication ambiguity

Tags: matrices

From this source [here](http://code.wikia.com/wiki/Matrix_multiplication), it says that matrix multiplication is given by this:

$AB = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{1,1}b_{1,1}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1}+...+a_{1,n}b_{p, 1} & ...\\ 
\vdots  & a_{m,1}b_{1,p}+a_{m,2}b_{2,p}+...+a_{m,n}b_{n,p}
\end{bmatrix}$

where the dimension of Matrix $A$ is $m\times n$ and dimension of Matrix $B$ is $n\times p$.

If we look at the top left element of $AB$, the final number in the sum ($a_{1,n}b_{p, 1}$).

It seems to me that this is very ambiguous, as it would only work if $n=p$. Otherwise we must stop at the point n or p, given whichever is smallest.

Can anyone clarify this with me, and if I am correct could someone maybe link me to a less ambiguous definition of matrix multiplication.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the final term in the top left position should be $a_{1,n},b_{n,1}$, with an $n$ and not a $p$

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. The correct formula is
$$ (AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k=1}^n A_{ik} B_{kj}, $$
where $1 \leq i \leq m$ and $1 \leq j \leq p$.

Also, $A$ and $B$ are not vectors but *matrices*.

Answer (score 0):

It is *lapsus calami*. The corect version is $a_{1,1}b_{1,1}+a_{1,2}b_{2,1}+...+a_{1,n}b_{n, 1}$. Easy to understand method is so called Falk's scheme. Here is the suggested link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuMS9u1ytN4 (in German, but self-explanatory).